# Elegantly "Untangling" an array of values into a hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array

```
[{:id=>1, :name=>"name"}, {:id=>2, :name=>"name2"}, {:id=>45, :name=>"name3"}]
```

What would be an **elegant** way to turn it into a hash ? (like so):

```
{1=>"name", 2=>"name2", 45=>"name3"}
```

Comment: Shall we assume that you already have working, but *inelegant* solution? Show it.

Comment: I did have one, but it was too inelegant to show ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr = [{:id=>1, :name=>"name"}, {:id=>2, :name=>"name2"}, {:id=>45, :name=>"name3"}]
hash = Hash[arr.map &:values]
# => {1=>"name", 2=>"name2", 45=>"name3"}
```

Documentation link: [Hash::[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D)

Comment: Note: Needs Ruby >= 1.9 (in 1.8, the order of hash items is unspecified)